Can a Noachide innovate practices that he considers non-religious but potentially of a supernatural nature?
Is it permissible for a Gentile to spend certain days of the week in a specific manner, in order to attain supernatural benefits such as from planetary rays which he might consider to be scientific and natural, as long as it is private and not intended to be a new religious practice?

Absolutely permissible provided the noachide in question checks in with a physicist and a psychologist beforehand

What if he goes by the opinions of Al Kindi etc on the matter, that is to say, he doesn't hold the practice to be supernatural. And if he does, is it considered idolatry given that he holds the planets to be inferior to God and partaking in their rays equivalent to benefitting from the world including its spiritual aspects without asking any favours as such.

What’s the “specific manner”? What are the practices in question?

Dressing in clothes of the color assigned to the planet,  listening to musical instruments corresponding to the planet, doing activities corresponding to the planet like learning a new language.

@HypostaticApophaticMystic I strongly suggest taking יהושע ק ‘s advice.
